# Spark job terminated, java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF while trying to read response from server

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I'm running a spark job in Amazon EMR, the job terminates with below error:

```
20/10/01 10:44:51 WARN DataStreamer: Exception for BP-1069374220-10.0.1.121-1601548370932:blk_1073741830_1006
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF while trying to read response from server
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelperClient.vintPrefixed(PBHelperClient.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PipelineAck.readFields(PipelineAck.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer$ResponseProcessor.run(DataStreamer.java:1073)
20/10/01 10:44:51 WARN DataStreamer: Error Recovery for BP-1069374220-10.0.1.121-1601548370932:blk_1073741830_1006 in pipeline [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.0.1.16:50010,DS-3736ee37-017b-419c-af06-57ff2a605389,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.0.1.25:50010,DS-7514c078-d287-4df4-b081-190f696b7794,DISK]]: datanode 0(DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.0.1.16:50010,DS-3736ee37-017b-419c-af06-57ff2a605389,DISK]) is bad.
20/10/01 10:46:46 WARN DataStreamer: Exception for BP-1069374220-10.0.1.121-1601548370932:blk_1073741830_1007
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF while trying to read response from server
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelperClient.vintPrefixed(PBHelperClient.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PipelineAck.readFields(PipelineAck.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer$ResponseProcessor.run(DataStreamer.java:1073)
```

Comment: Any code you can show so that your error would be reproductible?

Answer (score 0):

there may be some junk character in a file. Try to filter out those records or use this option condition while reading data .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")